# Issue with triggering events between private channels using Pusher in Flutter (pusher_channel_flutter package) and seeking alternative solutions

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, chat, pusher

We are facing a problem while using the pusher_channel_flutter package for implementing chat functionality in our Flutter app. Specifically, we are unable to trigger events between different private channels. We have two channels: "private-chat.2" for the sender and "private-chat.4" for the receiver, based on their respective user IDs.

Our current challenge is that we have only subscribed to "private-chat.2" and are unable to trigger an event from "private-chat.2" to "private-chat.4". It appears that the pusher_channel_flutter package does not provide a straightforward solution for this scenario.

We would like to explore alternative approaches that avoid making an API call to the server. Is there any way to trigger an event on the same channel from the APK itself without relying on client events, which are not useful in this case?

We appreciate any guidance, insights, or alternative suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:new_user_side/utils/extensions/extensions.dart';
import 'package:pusher_channels_flutter/pusher_channels_flutter.dart';

class PusherTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PusherTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PusherTest> createState() => _PusherTestState();
}

class _PusherTestState extends State<PusherTest> {
  PusherChannelsFlutter pusher = PusherChannelsFlutter.getInstance();
  String _log = 'output:\n';
  final apiKey = "";
  final cluster = "ap2";
  final channelName = "private-chat.2";
  final toChannelName = "private-chat.4";
  final String eventName = "message-sent";
  String token = "85|yZZhVY7zvwPG743n0alVzUncZ9hYDSXz4aGdCbt9";
  final _eventFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _listViewController = ScrollController();
  final _data = TextEditingController();

  void log(String text) {
    print("LOG: $text");
    setState(
      () {
        _log += text + "\n";
        Timer(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          () {
            _listViewController
                .jumpTo(_listViewController.position.maxScrollExtent);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    onConnectPressed();
  }

  void onConnectPressed() async {
    // Remove keyboard
    // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    try {
      await pusher.init(
        apiKey: apiKey,
        cluster: cluster,
        onConnectionStateChange: onConnectionStateChange,
        onError: onError,
        onSubscriptionSucceeded: onSubscriptionSucceeded,
        onEvent: onEvent,
        onSubscriptionError: onSubscriptionError,
        onDecryptionFailure: onDecryptionFailure,
        onMemberAdded: onMemberAdded,
        onMemberRemoved: onMemberRemoved,
        onSubscriptionCount: onSubscriptionCount,
        //authEndpoint: "https://meinhaus.ca/broadcasting/auth",
        onAuthorizer: onAuthorizer,
      );
      await pusher.subscribe(channelName: channelName);
      await pusher.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      log("ERROR: $e");
    }
  }

  void onConnectionStateChange(dynamic currentState, dynamic previousState) {
    log("Connection: $currentState");
  }

  void onError(String message, int? code, dynamic e) {
    log("onError: $message code: $code exception: $e");
  }

  void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
    ("New Event").log();
    log("onEvent: $event");
  }

  void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String channelName, dynamic data) {
    log("onSubscriptionSucceeded: $channelName data: $data");
    final me = pusher.getChannel(channelName)?.me;
    log("Me: $me");
  }

  void onSubscriptionError(String message, dynamic e) {
    log("onSubscriptionError: $message Exception: $e");
  }

  void onDecryptionFailure(String event, String reason) {
    log("onDecryptionFailure: $event reason: $reason");
  }

  void onMemberAdded(String channelName, PusherMember member) {
    log("onMemberAdded: $channelName user: $member");
  }

  void onMemberRemoved(String channelName, PusherMember member) {
    log("onMemberRemoved: $channelName user: $member");
  }

  void onSubscriptionCount(String channelName, int subscriptionCount) {
    log("onSubscriptionCount: $channelName subscriptionCount: $subscriptionCount");
  }

  dynamic onAuthorizer(
      String channelName, String socketId, dynamic options) async {
    print(options);
    var authUrl = "https://website/broadcasting/auth";
    var result = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(authUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
      },
      body: 'socket_id=' + socketId + '&channel_name=' + channelName + '',
    );
    var json = jsonDecode(result.body);
    print(json);
    print(json['auth']);
    return {
      "auth": json['auth'],
      //"channel_data": {"user_id": 2},
      "shared_secret": json["shared_secret"],
    };
  }

  void onTriggerEventPressed() async {
    if (_eventFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await pusher.trigger(
        PusherEvent(
          channelName: "private-chat.2",
          eventName: eventName,
          data: _data.text,
        ),
      );
      print("Event triggerd");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            pusher.connectionState == 'DISCONNECTED'
                ? 'Pusher Channels Example'
                : channelName,
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView(
            controller: _listViewController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              if (pusher.connectionState != 'CONNECTED')
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: onConnectPressed,
                  child: const Text('Connect'),
                )
              else
                Form(
                  key: _eventFormKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: pusher.channels[channelName]?.members.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final member = pusher
                              .channels[channelName]!.members.values
                              .elementAt(index);

                          return ListTile(
                              title: Text(member.userInfo.toString()),
                              subtitle: Text(member.userId));
                        },
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _data,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Data',
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: onTriggerEventPressed,
                        child: const Text('Trigger Event'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              SingleChildScrollView(child: Text(_log)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When we triggered an event for the different or the same channel from application we want to have it like API message not like a client event